# React Native App not working after building and install it on a device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

After building my app and installing the APK on a Emulator and a Device the app doesn't start. While I used Expo Go it worked perfectly. Any idea how to fix this?

I used this command to build it:

`eas build -p android --profile preview`

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_native_test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after following this steps:
https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff
i managed to get this error. :

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager
```

after this i used this 2 commands

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view


npm install @react-navigation/native
```

now it seems to work for the prebuild version. currently waiting for expo to build my apk. I have absolutely no idea how i should have found a solution for this error. i mean, yes i found it, but the procedure was absolutely random.